# Getting undefined then in returned promise after push in angularfire

Tags: javascript, firebase, database-normalization, angularfire2

I am trying to get the data that was just pushed to firebase so that i can use the `$key` in another push in an attempted to normalize the data. I am using angularfire 2 and ionic 2

I have a provider that returns a promise:

```
pushData(fbPath: string, data): any {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(this.af.database.list(fbPath).push(data));
    });
  });
}
```

And in the component I have a simple call which is called after a user fills out a form

```
 this.api.pushData('organisations/', organisation).then(org => {
    console.log(org);
 });
```

However in the `console.log` I get

[image]

Which is hardly usable. All I want in the return is the `$key` which is currently at `org.path.o[1]` which I guess I can use, but that seems a bit shaky.

Curious as to why the `then` and `catch` are undefined. What I would like is for the returned data to be a neat Object like so

```
 { 
   '$key':'-KfB5tltOeuXpQ_pRzR3',
   'name':'My New Organisation',
   'registeredDate':345345345345
 }
```

Which is fairly easy when getting the data from firebase, with a simple

```
getData(fbPath: string) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     this.af.database.list(fbPath).subscribe(res => resolve(res));
   });
}
```

In the [Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#saving-data) docs it states that the saving data ( in `.list` ) has a returned promise on the push method. I just cant seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In native firebase (not wrapped in angularfire2), when you get an weird-looking object like this, you can call .val() on it to get a neatly formatted object.

Did not verify, but highly likely that that will do the job.